# AdminClient self-signed certificates

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I am using in my program the com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient to connect to multiple DMGRs. The problem is that those servers are all using self signed certificates. Is there a way to force AdminClient to accept self signed certificates no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you create your admin client, you can set it so that it can auto-accept.  You set the AdminClient.CONNECTOR_AUTO_ACCEPT_SIGNER property to "true".

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient.html

You can also use the com.ibm.wsspi.ssl.RetrieveSignersHelper class to auto-accept signer-certificates.  You can call autoAcceptSignerAndStoreInTrustStore() or autoAcceptSignerForThisConnectionOnly().

For instance:

com.ibm.wsspi.ssl.RetrieveSignersHelper.getInstance().autoAcceptSignerForThisConnectionOnly();

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/spidocs/com/ibm/wsspi/ssl/RetrieveSignersHelper.html

Comment: Which of these suggestions was most helpful?